# transform a json file, into a new json

Tags: json, python-3.x, jq

```
{
    "prodid_876006": {
        "serid": [{
            "seridone": "3265874"
        }, {
            "seridtwo": "21458915"
        }],
        "serials": ["028915"]
    },
    "prodid_980": {
        "serid": [{
            "seridone": "32743214"
        }, {
            "seridtwo": "5469872"
        }],
        "serials": ["192147","1632589"]
    }
}

% jq '[to_entries[] | {"key": .key, "value": .value.serials}] | from_entries' some.json
```

gives:

```
{
  "prodid_876006": [
    "028915"
  ],
  "prodid_980": [
    "192147",
    "1632589"
  ]
}
```

how could i get the following output? (here the key is each element of the serials array, and the value is the key of the sample json):

```
{    
"028915" : ["prodid_876006"],
"192147" : ["prodid_980"],
"1632589" : ["prodid_980"]
}
```

Comment: Given how similar this question is to [another one you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42762941/78845), you might be better off describing the problem you are trying to solve, rather than how to implement the solution. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147331

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq create a new json by transforming an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762941/jq-create-a-new-json-by-transforming-an-existing-one)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses `reduce` within `reduce` and so might look a bit tricky, so it might help to think of "reduce" as a kind of "do loop", as suggested by the indentation:

```
reduce to_entries[] as $kv ({};
  reduce $kv.value.serials[] as $s (.;
    . + {($s): (.[$s] + [$kv|.key]) } ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **to_entries**, **reduce** and **add**

```
    [ to_entries[]
      | .key as $k
      | reduce .value.serials[] as $v ({}; .[$v] += [$k])
    ] | add
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, a more succinct way to get the first result in your question is to use `map_values`. You're changing all the values in your object map to the contents of the `serials` value. Which can be expressed simply as:

```
map_values(.serials)
```

From there, it's just a matter of pivoting the data.

```
map_values(.serials) | reduce to_entries[] as $e ({};
    .[$e.value[]] += [$e.key]
)
```