# use jq to reshape a json file

Tags: json, jq

i need to transform the following

input:

```
{
      "id-952": [
        "serial-8915"
      ],
      "id-546": [
        "serial-5747",
        "serial-8735"
      ]
```

Desired output:

```
{
"serial-8915": ["id-952"],
"serial-5747": ["id-546"],
serial-8735": ["id-546"]
}
```

my try, on jqplay:

```
keys, .[]
```

output:

```
[
  "id-546",
  "id-952"
]
[
  "serial-8915"
]
[
  "serial-5747",
  "serial-8735"
]
```

what jq command is the appropriate one?

Comment: try this `to_entries|map(.key as $keys |.value|map({"key":.,"value":[$keys]}))|flatten(2)|from_entries`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq create a new json by transforming an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762941/jq-create-a-new-json-by-transforming-an-existing-one)

Answer (score 1):

A very concise solution using [`with_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries), swapping keys and values:

```
with_entries({key:.value[], value:[.key]})
```

Output:

```json
{
  "serial-8915": [
    "id-952"
  ],
  "serial-5747": [
    "id-546"
  ],
  "serial-8735": [
    "id-546"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which uses **add**

```
. as $d | [ keys[] | {($d[.][]): [.]} ] | add
```

or equivalently

```
. as $d | keys | map( {($d[.][]):[.]} ) | add
```